# linked list segmentation fault a

Tags: c

After I'd say about 500 entries, this linked list code seg faults.

```
while (item_temp->next != 0) {
```

Inside the loop, all it does is goes to the next item in the linked list.

When I look at it in gdb, here's what I get

```
(gdb) print item_temp
$1 = (struct item *) 0xc
(gdb) print item_temp->next
Cannot access memory at address 0xc
```

EDIT:

I allocate it like so:

```
struct item* item_temp = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
```

and then right before the loop I set it equal to the head of the linked list like so

```
    item_temp = table->buckets[code]->head;
```

And just for sake of making it known, before I try to reference the head, I make sure the head exists. I do that like so.

```
if (table->buckets[code]->head == 0)
{
    table->buckets[code]->head = item_add;
    table->occupied_buckets++;
}
```

Here's a sample of my code... if you need something else, please ask.

```
struct HT* add(struct HT* table, struct word *wrd, int(*alg)(struct word *wrd)) 
{
if ((double)table->entries / (double)table->num_buckets > .75)
{
    table = resize(table, alg);
}   
sort(wrd);
int code = alg(wrd);
code = code % table->num_buckets;
struct item* item_temp = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
struct item* item_add = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
item_add->wrd = wrd;
item_add->next = 0; 
if (table->buckets[code]->head == 0)
{
    table->buckets[code]->head = item_add;
    table->occupied_buckets++;
}
else
{
    item_temp = table->buckets[code]->head;
    while (item_temp->next != 0) {
        item_temp = item_temp->next;
    }
    item_temp->next = item_add;
}
table->buckets[code]->num_items++;
table->entries++;
if (table->buckets[code]->num_items > table->largest_bucket)
{
    table->largest_bucket = table->buckets[code]->num_items;
}
return table;
   }
```

Comment: How do you expect any help with we can't see the code? Odds are that there are bugs in your code, which we can help with but only if we can see the code. This sounds like `NULL` pointer being dereferenced.

Comment: post the code block where you're allocating and initializing the linked list. This error looks like uninitialized memory.

Comment: what do you set the `next` member to for the very last node in the linked list ? Do you correctly set it to `0` ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker It should auto-set to null shouldn't it? Nonetheless, I added that line, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: `malloc` doesn't initialize memory, so it is not automatically set to `0`. If you fixed that, and are still having the issue, you'll need to show a representative (compilable) code sample.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it is clear that `item_temp` is pointing to location `0xc` and de-referencing `next` is causing the code to access an invalid address and hence, the segmentation fault.

`item_temp = table->buckets[code]->head;` is evaluating to `0xc`.

Comment: No, that is not clear at all. It's clear that `item_temp` is pointing at `0xc`, not the member. Dereferencing `item_temp` to read `next` is what's causing the fault.